# Should I be more lenient in approving suggested edits to community wikis?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-wiki

I ran across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8421826) to a community wiki post.  The user who proposed the edit had only 40 rep and did not have the 100 rep privilege to edit community wikis.

I didn't really know how to handle this suggested edit so I skipped it.  My gut reaction (if it was not a community wiki) would be to reject the edit because it "clearly conflicts with author's intent."  The edit changed some exception code, and even though the edit comment explained the rationale behind it, I felt it misrepresented the actual answer.  And this edit felt more like a comment/downvote (but the user didn't have those privileges).  Of course I'm not so sure the the author didn't intend for these kinds of edits since it's a community wiki.

So I have two questions:

- If the post had been a regular post is my initial reaction to reject the edit correct?
- Do/should we treat suggested edits to community wikis differently?  And in this case does the fact that the post is a community wiki make the edit approvable?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> If the post had been a regular post is my initial reaction to reject the edit correct?

Yes.

> Do/should we treat suggested edits to community wikis differently?

Yes.  The point of making a post CW is to say that it is no longer *your post*.  Rather it is a collaboration of many people, and that the person who posted it is encouraging others to edit the *content*, and not just the *presentation* of the answer, so long as those edits are correct.

So on short, the CW posts should never reject edits because it conflicts with the author's intent, as the intent of the author is to allow others to change the content.

> And in this case does the fact that the post is a community wiki make the edit approvable?

It means that the edit should be judged on its merits; it should be approved if it improves the content of the post.  I personally have no idea if the edit that was made is a good thing to do or not.  If it's a better solution, it should be approved, if it's a worse solution it should be rejected, and if you're not qualified to judge it on its technical merits then you should skip it.

Comment: +1 for last clause, which should be re-emphasized for a lot of code changes in answers.

Comment: It's not really even a question of better or worse. What's in the answer *now* is just plain wrong and doesn't work. But that is still hard to tell, and still a good reason to skip the review.

Comment: Huh. IMHO if the change proposer sounds like they know what they're talking about, you should approve. The chance that the change is positive is much greater than the chance that it's negative, and skipping just means it will take even longer to get approved.

Comment: @SteveBennett No, by approving the edit you're taking responsibility for the correctness of that edit.  If you have no idea whether or not it's appropriate, you should be skipping the edit, not just assuming it's correct.  Keep in mind that the consequences of approving a harmful edit are *dramatically* more significant than the edit simply taking a bit longer to be approved, if it's really correct.

Comment: Probably the OP will see the change and complain, and it will get sorted out. The idea that people with edit approval privileges know more about a subject than casual users of StackOverflow is absurd and patronising.

Comment: @SteveBennett That's assuming the OP is active, which is often not the case at all.  The idea that the first three people that see the edit will know if it's appropriate is absurd.  The idea that there will never ever be three people who could judge the quality of the edit is not.  And how you think that literally approving everything without regard for what it's doing is appropriate is *far* more absurd in my eyes.

Comment: In all the post edits I've reviewed, I've almost never seen a wrong change. People just don't make edits that turn a right thing into a wrong thing. Trust people!

Comment: @SteveBennett And I've seen many dozens of incorrect changes to the technical content.  Heck, I had a completely invalid edit that completely trashed code that was previous completely correct made to one of my post [just yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30852611/2).  (That wasn't an edit that required review, but the point should stand.)  Also you've only review ~300 edits, and you've said that you *almost* never see a wrong change.  If you've even see like 2-3 of them then that's ~1% of the reviews you've had.  If 1% of suggested edits are breaking the answer that's *very* bad.

Comment: I'd be very happy with a 99:1 improvement:crap ratio.

Comment: @SteveBennett I wasn't saying that 99% of edits are good edits.  I was saying that there's probably only a percent or two that are completely breaking the answer. There are plenty of edits that are either not helpful, or are problematic, but for completely different reasons.  In my experiences at least 25% of edits merit rejection.  For these particular bad edits though approving an edit that completely breaks an answer is *much* more harmful than an edit that makes a small improvement to its presentation.  Just one is causing more harm than dozens, if not hundreds, of other edits are helping.

Comment: Ok, I hear what you're saying. I think you're probably being more conservative than necessary but I take your point and I'll look at future reviews in that light.